# SFML: Platforms disappearing after push_back()

Tags: c++, sfml

New to C++, I'm trying to make "platforms" spawn every 2 seconds and go upwards. However, the platform disappears when a new `Platform` is pushed onto the `platforms` vector.

Platform.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <vector>

class Platform
{
private:
    sf::RectangleShape shape;
public:
    Platform() = default;
    Platform(const Platform& platform);

    void updatePos();
    sf::RectangleShape getShape() { return shape; }
};
```

Platform.cpp:

```
#include "Platform.h"

Platform::Platform(const Platform& platform)
{
    shape.setSize(sf::Vector2f(300.f, 40.f));
    shape.setPosition(1920.f / 2.f - shape.getSize().x / 2.f, 1080.f);
}

void Platform::updatePos()
{
    shape.move(sf::Vector2f(0.f, -5.f));
}
```

Game.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Platform.h"
#include <iostream>

class Game
{
private:
    sf::RenderWindow window{ sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080), "Dodge the Spikes", sf::Style::Fullscreen };
    std::vector<Platform> platforms;
    bool gameOver{};
    unsigned int platformTimer{};
public:
    Game() = default;
    void update();
    void draw();
    void run();
};
```

Game.cpp:

```
#include "Game.h"

void Game::update()
{
    if (!gameOver)
    {
        //spawn platforms
        platformTimer++;
        if (platformTimer >= 120)
        {
            platforms.push_back(Platform{});
            platformTimer = 0;
        }
        
        //update platforms
        for (auto i{platforms.begin()}; i < platforms.end();)
        {
            i->updatePos();
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void Game::draw()
{
    for (auto i{ platforms.begin() }; i < platforms.end();)
    {
        window.draw(i->getShape());
        i++;
    }
}

void Game::run()
{
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt))
        {
            if (evnt.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        this->update();
        window.clear();

        this->draw();
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your copy constructor doesn't copy, I suspect that can be the core issue.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks, it worked after I moved the code from the copy constructor to a regular constructor, but I'm a little confused on why the copy constructor can't just be used to "set up" the `shape` object instead, since I've read that copy constructors are used when using `push_back()`

Comment: The role of of copy constructor is to create a copy of the object. If you break that agreement, a lot of weird things is going to happen. Especially because `std::vector` can create copies when reallocating to biggger storage, without you knowing when that happens.

Comment: Unrelated: I have never seen that iteration pattern before. Since you seem to be compiling as C++11, why not use the far simpler `for (const auto& platform: platforms) { ... }`?